# Change color of GeoJSON polyline in dash-leaflet

Tags: python, leaflet, geojson, dash

I am adding two GeoJSON polyline layers to a leaflet window in a dash app using callbacks like this:

```
dl.Map(children=[dl.TileLayer(), dl.GeoJSON(id="geojson1"), dl.GeoJSON(id="geojson2")])
```

How do I change the color of the second GeoJSON polyline to yellow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the color inside the options parameter, inside a style dict, like this

```
dl.Map(children=[dl.TileLayer(), dl.GeoJSON(id="geojson1"), dl.GeoJSON(options={"style":{"color":"yellow"}}, id="geojson2")])
```